# Where is Light in Game view

Tags: unity, lighting

Very Basic Question.when i run the the game the game Mode is Too dark as shown below in the picture. please suggest me some Setting how to globally switch on built in light while Running the game in game mode.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: For an asset like the background image you're showing here, you probably don't want it affected by lighting at all. Try adding it as a Sprite, or changing its Material to use one of the Unlit shaders.

Comment: agree and additional explanation: The word "unlit" is kinda misleading; it doesn't mean "no light", it means "not affected by lights in the scene". So the image is simply rendered directly with no consideration about light sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "ambient light," and is the common term for most game engines.

You can find more information about Unity's ambient light, fog, and other global scene settings here: [Unity Manual - Render Settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderSettings.html)

Comment: Yes it works.Tanks A lot